# ASP MVC 5 HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated is still TRUE after IIS app pool recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, appdomain, owin-middleware

On IIS app pool recycle HttpContext.Current.Session items are null but HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated is **TRUE**, how this this can be set false. We are using OWIN middleware Cookie based authentication scheme. Authorize filter is checking  HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated value and ActionFilter is further pre-checking HttpContext.Current.Session items value for further action.

On appdomain recycle  Authorize filter get the HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated value as **TRUE** so request is passed to ActionFilter, inside action filter session values are null so request got stuck for further processing. Is there any solution,configuration exist which will set  HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated value to **FALSE** on appdomain recycle.

Comment: You should generally be aiming for AppDomain recycles to be *transparent* to users. It sounds like you're trying to work in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I can not understand your comment, what you mean by opposite direction. Can you please explain.